# Is there any drawback if i convert a string to Double then compare the result to integer value (such as 2000, 1000)

Tags: c#

I am not sure if i am doing things correctly inside my asp.net application. now i have 3 fields which represents currency fields, which allow maximum of 2 decimals:-

- OneTimeCost
- MonthlyCost
- AnnualCost

and i am calculating this value:-

```
var totalcost = double.Parse(currentItem["OnTimeCost"].ToString()) + (double.Parse(currentItem["MonthlyCost"].ToString()) * 12) + double.Parse(currentItem["AnnualCost"].ToString());
```

then i am comparing the result as follow:-

```
if( totalcost >= 2000)
{
}
else if (totalcost > 1000)
{
}
//and so on
```

Now i am not sure if i am doing things correctly or not? now the 3 fields i have, represents currency values which can allow 2 decimal points. so not sure if converting my values to double and then compare the result to integer values (2000 and 1000) is a correct and safe operation?

second question. is it better to use `decimal.parse` instead of `double.parse`? since decimal is more appropriate for financial calculations ?

Comment: For financial calculations use `decimal` type instead of `double`. Constant `2000` in decimal is `2000M`. But logically seems better to define `const decimal Limit_1 = 2000M` for example and then compare `totalcost >= Limit_1` instead of numeric value.

Comment: @i486 thanks for the reply. so can i know why decimal is more appropriate than double in my case?

Comment: Calculations involving floating-point values are subject to rounding errors, which is why `decimal` is better-suited to financial calculations.

Comment: @MarkBenningfield so i need to replace  all the current `double.parse` with`decimal.parse` is this correct?

Comment: Along with changing the `double` variable definitions to `decimal`, and changing the `double` literals to `decimal` literals.

Answer (score 1):

> so not sure if converting my values to double and then compare the
>   result to integer values (2000 and 1000) is a correct and safe
>   operation?

Yes, it's safe.

> second question. is it better to use decimal.parse instead of
>   double.parse? since decimal is more appropriate for financial
>   calculations ?

if you're dealing with money then use `decimal` as that's why it's there.

Comment: @Anomine thanks for the reply. but can i know where my application can fail if i keep using double instead of decimal ?  second point, is it better to define my integer numbers as `2000.00` and `1000.00` instead of `2000` and `1000`

Comment: Given what you've mentioned in your description I don't see how `double` floating point numbers will make your application fail, it's just that currencies are usually better represented with `decimal` floating point numbers. as for your second question, if you're using doubles then you can specify the number explicitly as a floating point number like `if( totalcost >= 2000.00)` but even if you do `if( totalcost >= 2000)` the compiler will cast the `2000` to a double prior to the comparison of `totalcost >= 2000` so you're not forced to explicitly specify the literal value as a floating point.

Comment: @Anomine now using `double.Parse(currentItem["OnTimeCost"].ToString()) + (double.Parse(currentItem["MonthlyCost"].ToString()) * 12) + double.Parse(currentItem["AnnualCost"].ToString()); ` equation.. i have submitted the following calculations `1.23 + (0.45 * 12) + 0.67` now using my calculator the result should be 7.3, but inside visual studio i got `7.30000000000001` not sure if this is due to using double instead of decimal?

Comment: not able to replicate that as I am getting `7.3` but if you only want up to 2 decimal places maximum then you can always do `double result = Math.Truncate(100 * someValue) / 100;` to truncate it.